# Adaptable grid of images with not the same size

Tags: css, grid, responsive-design, multiple-columns, fluid-layout

I don't really know if this has a solution, but would be awesome if someone knew it!

I just wanna use CSS and javascript if needed.

**What I have:**

A grid of images, no white space whatsoever. Actually I implemented inside responsive columns with *column-count*

**What I want**

Each image is 100% size inside the column, I want them to be bigger when you hover them. What happens is that they grow but they do behind everything (you can see [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/379163/CC3Cuero/productos.html))
If i just put every image with no columns, just being displayed inline-block, then when an image grows it leaves white space in the rest of the row.

Is there a way so every image can stick together (no white space) even when one of them grows?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
a:hover img, a:focus img {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

to bring the bigger images to the front.